# Method to recursively delete any directory that has no files, my solution seems to work but trying to find ways it can break

Tags: java

This method will delete any files and empty directories provided in the fileList. It seems to be working. I use recursion to delete the empty directories and i'm worried about cases that will create an infinite loop. Any thoughts or things to consider with this approach?

```
public static void deleteFilesAndEmptyDirs(List<File> fileList) {
            boolean result = true;
            List<File> returnList = new LinkedList<File>();
            for (File file : fileList) {
                result = file.delete();
                if(result == false && file.isDirectory()) {
                    returnList.add(file);
                }
            }

            if(returnList.size() >= 1) {
                deleteFilesAndEmptyDirs(returnList);
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you can not delete a file (for example because of a Linux permissions issue) then what happens? I think it would be better to throw an IOException, than to try again infinitely.

Comment: btw, instead of testing `result==false`, simply use `!result`. Instead of using `returnList.size() >= 1` you can either use `returnList.size() > 0` or `!returnList.isEmpty()`

Comment: @GuillaumePolet +1 for readability

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In linux, you can create a recursive link between two directories.

E.g, I made these two dirs:

```
$ ls -Rla
.:
total 24
drwxr-xr-x   4 dave dave  4096 2012-04-09 17:26 .
drwxr-xr-x 111 dave dave 12288 2012-04-09 17:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x   2 dave dave  4096 2012-04-09 17:27 dir1
drwxr-xr-x   2 dave dave  4096 2012-04-09 17:27 dir2

./dir1:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 dave dave 4096 2012-04-09 17:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 dave dave 4096 2012-04-09 17:26 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave dave    8 2012-04-09 17:27 dir2 -> ../dir2/

./dir2:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 dave dave 4096 2012-04-09 17:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 dave dave 4096 2012-04-09 17:26 ..
lrwxrwxrwx 1 dave dave    8 2012-04-09 17:27 dir1 -> ../dir1/
```

then I can do this:

```
 $ cd dir1/dir2/dir1/dir2/dir1/dir2/dir1/
```

Which if not checked for would cause a stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

Your method will recurse infinitely if it encounters a non empty directory.  You have to add the contents of the nonempty directory to the list of files to delete.

I believe (but have not tested) that the below code is robust to [recursive symbolic links](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10076335/348975).

```
public static void deleteFilesAndEmptyDirs(List<File> fileList) {
            boolean result = true;
            List<File> returnList = new LinkedList<File>();
            for (File file : fileList) {
                result = file.delete();
                if(result == false && file.isDirectory()) {
                  for ( File f : file . listFiles ( ) ) {
                    returnList.add(f);
                  }
                  returnList . add ( file ) ;
                }
            }

            if(returnList.size() >= 1) {
                deleteFilesAndEmptyDirs(returnList);
            }
        }
```